# which is better way to confirm email: by activation(not allowed to login) or confirmation(allowed to login)

Tags: email-verification

I want user to register before access the android app.

The username will be email address.

Somehow i want the user to confirm his email because its the only way he can recover his password if he forgets it.

So i found there are two occasions he can confirm his email.

1) User activation link sent to his email and he click it. Till that time he is not allowed to login in

2) User confirmation link send to his email and he clicks it. Till that time he is allowed.

The first method has no ambiguity because unless the user clicks the activation there will be not be any way to move ahead. But it can be little uncomfortable to the user because he have to wait.

the second method is bit confusing in regard to how long we have to keep informing the user to confirm his email. And we have to restrict access to certain features til he confirms his email.

Which is the better and keep it simple way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you state, the first method is **an inconvenience to the user**:

> The first method has no ambiguity because unless the user clicks the
>   activation there will be not be any way to move ahead. But it can be
>   little uncomfortable to the user because he have to wait.

Continuing, you state that the second method is **an inconvenience to the developer**, as there are several additional questions about how exactly this method should be implemented:

> the second method is bit confusing in regard to how long we have to
>   keep informing the user to confirm his email. And we have to restrict
>   access to certain features til he confirms his email.

Therefore, the path that would likely provide the best experience *for the user* would be the second. This would allow the user to immediately engage with you application, and can confirm their account at their convenience.

Answer (score 1):

If your app is not specifically something which holds very sensitive information, then you can let users continue without mail verification, but a notice should be shown that verify your e-mail. And of-course restrict few features which can be misused without verified e-mail. For an example, I made an app where users could share any item with other people through e-mail ID. We restricted this feature for non-verified e-mail account holders. But other than that, you can let them continue using. Also, keeping a notice is a good practice, like if they feel they will continue using your app, eventually it will start irritate them, and that will trigger them to verify their E-mail address.

In case, your app is super-sensitive or business focused, then you can do following -

1. User inputs their E-mail ID
2. You notify the user that a verification link has been sent to your e-mail ID to perform next steps.
3. User checks email and click on the verification link
4. You open a form to fill up rest of the information other than E-mail like Name, Password etc.

So, from the very beginning, you got a verified user. Anyway, that's just a suggestion. You can let them verify later or can lock the account if 3 days over. This is just based on the type of business you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

As a user I would ask myself why I have to register first before seeing any value. I'd rather refuse using this app which makes your question obsolete.

Comment: I am developeing an app which will recieve an article daily. The user may want to add some articles to favorites and later view them. I can store them in the app local database. But when he clears the cache or delete and reinstall the app he will not be able to see his favorites. So if he has some username i can show him back his articles

Comment: Ah so. This is only one feature of your app. Why restrict access to the other features (reading articles or their preview)?